# Create managed instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to create a managed instance with AWS.

I followed this page to create the IAM role:https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/setup-instance-profile.html.

So it is `AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore`

This is the code I am using to associate the IAM role with the EC2.

```
    # Make EC2s with AWS Ubuntu 20
    instances = subnet.create_instances(ImageId='ami-0885b1f6bd170450c',
                                        InstanceType='m1.small', 
                                        MaxCount=num,
                                        MinCount=num,
                                        Monitoring={'Enabled': True},
                                        SubnetId=subnet.subnet_id,
                                        KeyName=key_name,
                                        IamInstanceProfile={
                                            'Arn': 'arn goes here',
                                        },)

    wait_until_running(instances)
```

And when I check in the console the role shows up.

But when I do
`aws ssm describe-instance-information`

I get

```
{
    "InstanceInformationList": []
}
```

The ultimate goal here is to be able to send a command to the instance.

Comment: What exactly is the instance role and what does `'Arn': '*'` mean?

Comment: Instance role is AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore  and that was just my way of saying its a placeholder. I have clarified both

Comment: So the instance shows in SSM Console under managed instances, but not when used `describe-instance-information`? Or it does not show up at all?

Comment: It doesn't show up there either.

Comment: Does the instance have internet access?

Comment: None have public IP addresses if that is what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The instance does not have public IP address, which indicates it likely has **no access to SSM service**.

For SSM to work on your instance, it must be able to **connect to the SSM service**. This is usually enabled in one of three ways:

1. Instance is a **public subnet** and has direct internet access.
2. Instance is in a **private subnet** and uses NAT gateway to access internet.
3. Your VPC uses [VPC interface endpoints for SSM service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/setup-create-vpc.html#sysman-setting-up-vpc-create) to connect to the SSM service. This does not require internet access and provides private communication between instance and the SSM service.

Comment: If adding a public IP address did not fix it would you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @Keiros Does the instance have internet connection now? Can you ssh into it?

Comment: Okay so now the ones I manually create do show up it just takes some time. So this is resolved I think :) thank you!

Comment: @Keiros No problem. Glad it worked out :-)